# Subspace of Endomorphisms of a vector space of doubly-infinite

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, laurent-series

I am reading this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=bB3UBwAAQBAJ&pg=PP11&dq=Introduction%20to%20Vertex%20Operator%20Algebras%20and%20Their%20Representations&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIsaKeh7SbyAIVA_I-Ch30wgsE#v=onepage&q=Introduction%20to%20Vertex%20Operator%20Algebras%20and%20Their%20Representations&f=false) about vertex Operator Algebra; I have difficulty understanding and verifying  this statement in page 26:-

> Consider $Hom(V, V ((x)))$ as a natural subspace of $(End\, V)[[x , x^{-1}]]$.

Where $V$ and $V((x))$ are vector space (the latter is space of truncatedformal Laurent series).
and $V[[x,x^{-1}]]$ is the vector space of (doubly infinite) formal Laurent series in X with coefficients in V.
any explanation or making sense of this statement appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it should be clear that $V((x))$ is a subspace of $V[[x, x^{-1}]]$:  The former only allows finitely many negative powers of $x$, while the latter allows infinitely many positive or negative powers of $x$.

Now let's consider an element $\phi \in Hom(V, V((x)))$.  Then $\phi: V \to V((x))$, and we can denote the image of an element $v\in V$ by $\phi(v) = \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}v_nx^n$, where $v_n\in V$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, we have an element, $v_n\in V$, which is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\phi(v)$.  Denote the mapping from $v\mapsto v_n$ by $\phi_n$, and observe that $\phi_n\in End(V)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Therefore, $\phi$ defines an element of $End(V)[[x, x^{-1}]]$, given explicitly by $\phi = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\phi_n x^n$.

It is often helpful to keep in mind that we usually don't think of formal power series (or formal Laurent series) as functions of $x$:  There is no topology or convergence here.  Rather, for the purposes of understanding these spaces, think of $\phi$ as a generating function for a family of endomorphisms of $V$, and consider the Laurent series notation merely a convenient way of indexing these endomorphisms.

Comment: thanks; but my question now is :- assume $\sum_{n=Z}^{\infty}v_nx^n \in V[[x,x^{-1}]]$ what will the image of this element look like under the $\phi$ that is  $ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\phi_n x^n \sum_{m=Z}^{\infty}v_m x^m$ will be equal to what.

Comment: @henry I don't quite understand your comment.  Think of the $\phi$ I described above in two ways:  First, as an element of $Hom(V, V((x)))$, $\phi$ maps an element $v\in V$ to a formal power series $\phi(v) = \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \phi(v)_nx^n$.  So $\phi(v)_n$ is an element of $V$.  The mapping $\phi_n: v\mapsto \phi(v)_n$ is an endomorphism of $V$.  Therefore, $\phi$ defines a family of endomorphisms ${\phi_n}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$, and this is how we see $\phi$ as an element of $End(V)[[x, x^{-1}]]$.